# Заглушка Assembly_Load

Tags: c#, c++

Подскажите что делает данная функция?
В c++ не особо,но если пойму что делает сделаю заглушку на C# или DLLIMPORT

```
bool MonoProcess::DisableAssemblyLoadCallback()
    {
        /*
        *   Ref: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/mono/blob/unity-staging/mono/metadata/assembly.c
        *
        *   => AssemblyLoadHook *assembly_load_hook = NULL;
        *   AssemblyLoadHook is a global variable that holds all the callbacks that needs to be fired when an assembly is loaded.
        *   
        *   Plan is to get an hold of it, null the pointer and restore it after loading our injected assembly.
        */

        if (m_OriginalAssemblyLoadPtrVal == NULL)
        {
            if (m_AssemblyLoadPtr == NULL)
            {
                auto exportData = m_InnerProcess.modules().GetExport(m_MonoModule, "mono_assembly_invoke_load_hook");

            #ifdef USE32
                auto assemblyLoadHookRefAddr = exportData->procAddress + 6;
                m_AssemblyLoadPtr = m_InnerProcess.memory().Read<int>(assemblyLoadHookRefAddr).result();
            #else
                auto assemblyLoadHookRefAddr = exportData->procAddress + 13;
                int assemblyLoadHookOffset = m_InnerProcess.memory().Read<int>(assemblyLoadHookRefAddr).result();
                m_AssemblyLoadPtr = (exportData->procAddress + 17) + assemblyLoadHookOffset;
            #endif              
            }

            //Keep the original pointer value so we can restore it.
            m_OriginalAssemblyLoadPtrVal = m_InnerProcess.memory().Read<blackbone::ptr_t>(m_AssemblyLoadPtr).result();

            //Null the pointer so it doesn't points to existing callback list anymore
            m_InnerProcess.memory().Write<blackbone::ptr_t>(m_AssemblyLoadPtr, 0);

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Получает адрес ссылки на сборку из таблицы экспорта модуля процесса, читает из этого адреса адрес сборки m_OriginalAssemblyLoadPtrVal и потом затирает в таблице экспорта сам адрес. Странный код. Интересно, для чего он?

Comment: @Александр скрывает AssemblyLoad - вы можете посоветовать как это обнаружить?

Comment: обнаружить что? Расскажите, что вы хотите сначала?

Comment: @Александр данный код выключает callback Assembly.Load - мне нужно узнать есть ли способ это зафиксировать и предотвратить